# Fork How to Kill A process with PID

Tags: c, linux, fork

Hi all I have to run a binary file using c++ and kill it.

My code look like

```
static int PROCESS_PID=0;

void startService(bool startservice){

if(startservice==true){
 pid_t PID = fork();
 if(PID == 0) {
   PROCESS_PID = getpid();
   printf("the child's pid is: %d\n", PROCESS_PID);
   system("./process");
 }
}

else{
 kill(PROCESS_PID, SIGUSR1); //kill process inside child process
 }

}
```

But when I kill the process the entire program get exited.
Any Idea ? Is there anything wrong with my code ?

Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `system()` you are starting a third process -- one which you do not have the pid for. Use `exec()` instead.

Worse though, your `kill()` call is only made in the case that `startservice!=true`, and in this case `PROCESS_PID==0`... so you're killing process 0 (which will send the signal to *all* processes in your current process group).

Comment: Actually I was using exec() instead of system() system but not working

Comment: The two calls are not equivalent; one is not a substitute for the other... so your work-around isn't a work-around that meets your needs. Post (in a new question) your real problem, the exec failure, so that the real problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you are double-`fork()`ing, as `system()` will perform a `fork()`/`exec()` in order to execute the command you want to run.

If you want better control of the child process (including killing it) then write your own version of `system()` where you perform the `fork()` and `exec()` yourself.

There are many examples of how to do this knocking around the internet.

Comment: Actually I was using exec() instead of system() system but not working

Comment: @Haris Then your question should focus on *that* code, not the code you posted.