# Creating num processes with fork and then deleting some that i will not use

Tags: c, fork, child-process

Okay so i am making a program and i am creating a number of child processes with fork, letting user decide their number, as such

```
for(int i=1;i<=number;i++){
        pid_t pid;
        if((pid=fork())<0){
            perror("fork failed");
        }else if(pid==0){ //is a child
            exit(0);
        }
    }
for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
        wait(NULL);
```

If the user wants me to create 5 and i create them, but later in my program I only want to use the first 4 lets say, how do i "delete" the last process?

Comment: What method are you using to assign work to a child process? It's very simple to have the child process just `exit` if it does not receive anything useful to do.

Comment: As a side note, you should refrain from counting from `1` unless there is a good reason to do so. Virtually every person reading your code and sees `for (int i = 1; i <= foo; i++)` will assume there is a bug in that loop.

Comment: A similar question already exists: [kill process with PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697493/fork-how-to-kill-a-process-with-pid).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fork How to Kill A process with PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697493/fork-how-to-kill-a-process-with-pid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `kill`:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
kill(child_pid, SIGKILL);
```

---

**Edit**

If you want the child process to do some cleanup before exiting, use SIGTERM instead, and in the child process implement a signal handler. Parent:

```
kill(child_pid, SIGTERM);
```

Child:

```c
void on_sig_term(int sig_num)
{
    \\ cleanup
    return;
}
signal(SIGTERM, on_sig_term);
```